# Does DataGrip by JetBrains support PL/SQL development?

Tags: oracle, plsql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

JetBrains website displays multiple useful features of their Database IDE, including code generation as per https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/generation.html; However the website does not explicitly declare support for PL/SQL.

Can any DataGrip users give a review in regards to the level of PL/SQL support in the IDE?

Comment: DataGrip supports PL/SQL development.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to download trial version (fully working; 30 days) and make the judgement yourself. The idea is -- different people will have different requirements/expectations from the tool: some will find this feature useful while some may dislike the way it works etc. Check their blog as well -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne I will try their 30-day free trial.

Answer (score 4):

For PL/SQL development I personally would recommend plugin [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) for IntelliJ IDEA if you don't want to use "oldshool" IDE-s like SQL Developer etc. Comparing to Datagrip it's more oriented to PL/SQL package development, but if you need to work with triggers - you need Datagrip, as mentioned plugin doesn't support modifying triggers.